# Unable to run Sabre Red App in Sandbox mode

Tags: java, exception, sabre

I went through 'Getting Started with Red App Development'. Looks like the Red App cab be run in Sandbox mode when neither CERT nor PROD environment is accessible. We are in the process to get the login credential for CERT and PROD environment. Meanwhile, I wanted to run the RedApp product in the Sandbox mode.

Per the ‘Getting Started with Red App Development’ document, added the following VM argument to the run environment:

```
Dredapp.fake.session=true
```

Ran the RedApp product, but could not get through the VPN login page.

I found following exceptions in the log :

```
SEVERE: Exception occured during copying 'hssp-mapping_SVPNMapping_HSSP_sabre.com.properties' file to the workspace
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\jjha\.jsapi\hssp-mapping_SVPNMapping_HSSP_sabre.com.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)



SEVERE: Exception occured during copying 'hssp-mapping_SVPNMapping_HSSP_sabre.com.properties' file to the workspace
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Jay\runtime-RedAppRun\emulator_files\hostinfo_svpn.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

What is the fix for the above issues/exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking on the Validate Plugins option, from the Plugins Tab?

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Fplugins.htm

Answer (score 0):

Below is the fix for the issue:

1. Launch the Red App
2. click tools->Options->Sabre System>Connection, and select 'Private network' instead of 'SSL VPN'